# position:fixed moving floated elements

Tags: html, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to create a fixed navigation bar with buttons(aligned left) and a title(aligned right). Before i fixed the position to the top of the page, it works as intended (other than not moving when scrolling, obviously). However, when i fix the position of the header, it moves my title over to the left with the buttons. How can I fix this? I've tried to make it into a div inside of the header tag and position:absolute the div; didn't work.

[image: Here is my code]

Here is what my page looks like
[image: Here is what my page looks like]

Comment: Post the code as text instead of image.

Comment: Add a width to the header. Fixed elements don't have the full page width by default.